# Deleting a dynamic array after it has been returned from a function

Tags: c++, memory, dynamic

I am new to C++ and paranoid of memory leaks. I'll strip my code down to just the important bits:

If I have a function like this:

```
char * myString = "Discombobulate";

char * ToUppercase()
{
    int length = strlen(myString);
    char * duplicateString = new char [length];
    strcpy(duplicateString, myString);
    //char arithmetic to turn every letter in duplicateString to uppercase
    return duplicateString;
}
```

Obviously, I need to perform a delete[] to avoid memory leaks. Now what I wanted to know is if I can do the delete in main(), like so:

```
int main () {
char * result = Upper();

std::cout << result << std::endl;

delete[] result;
}
```

Will this work properly? Is there any catch to doing it like this?

Comment: Why are you using `char*` in C++ instead of `std::string`? Also, your function names mismatch.

Comment: Use the RAII idiom. Return classes with value semantics that will manage such resources. In this instance, just return a `std::string` instead.

Comment: `strcpy(duplicateString, myString);` is undefined behavior, `duplicateString` is one char too short (no space for null char), just in case you needed another reason to use `std::string`.

Comment: Crappy example I know, I typed it up in about 2 seconds.

Comment: If you are paranoid of memory leaks you should stick to contemporary C++. Use RAII wrappers around resources, e.g. std::vector instead of C-style arrays. If you are learning from a book, and it introduces std::vector after C-arrays or std::string after C string handling I would throw it away.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Now what I wanted to know is if I can do the delete in main()

Yes, you can and you should.

BTW1: Think about using [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), [smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/smart_pointers), to avoid such kind of manual memory management, since it's c++.

BTW2:

```
char * duplicateString = new char [length];
```

should be

```
char * duplicateString = new char [length + 1];
```

The last position will be used for the terminating null character `'\0'`.

Comment: Yeah, I typed up the example fairly carelessly.

Answer (score 2):

> Will this work properly?

Yes. As long as it is a valid pointer, you could `delete` it outside of the function that called `new`. Should you? Well...

> Is there any catch to doing it like this?

Yes. It's bad practice. You're allocating resources in a function and expecting the caller to clean them up. It goes against RAII, as people in the comments have explained. Along with the advice to use `std::string` (do use it), you can use `std::unique_ptr` and friends instead of raw pointers.

Answer (score 1):

YEs you can delete it the way you have... By the way, you can also assign memory for the pointer and pass that as a parameter to the function and delete it after it returns from the function.

```
char * duplicateString = new char [length + 1];

ToUppercase(char* duplicateString );

if( duplicateString ){ delete []duplicateString  ; duplicateString  = NULL;}
```